# SQL two select clause at once

Tags: mysql, sql

From table

```
Name | Zone
AAA    1
BBB    2
CCC    3
DDD    1
...    ...
```

I want to get Name of Zone=1 and Zone=2 each at once.

I used two select clauses before, like

```
SELECT Name FROM ... WHERE ZONE=1
SELECT Name FROM ... WHERE ZONE=2
```

But above query searches the ZONE column twice.

**I want to find it **at once** because my table has actually >100million rows**

How can I get result like below by at once(least cost)?

```
Zone=1 | Zone=2
AAA      BBB
DDD      NULL
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I return pivot table output in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

How about `in`?

```
select zone, name
from t
where zone in (1, 2);
```

Comment: Sadly, this way can't distinguish the name by zone :(